# OC Cluster never goes up Error: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

When ever i try to get the cluster up using "oc cluster up"
Below is the error I get. Kindly help on how to fix this

```
[mano@mano ~]$ oc cluster up
Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
Checking type of volume mount ...
Determining server IP ...
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
Checking if OpenShift client is configured properly ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 ...
I0923 13:40:32.364326   15396 config.go:40] Running "create-master-config"
I0923 13:40:59.938492   15396 config.go:46] Running "create-node-config"
I0923 13:41:10.721711   15396 flags.go:30] Running "create-kubelet-flags"
I0923 13:41:18.241285   15396 run_kubelet.go:49] Running "start-kubelet"
I0923 13:41:23.016238   15396 run_self_hosted.go:181] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
E0923 13:46:23.023479   15396 run_self_hosted.go:571] API server error: Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused ()
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

OC version

```
[mano@mano` ~]$ oc version
oc v3.11.0+0cbc58b
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
```

followed the article :https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/release-3.11/docs/cluster_up_down.md
yet no luck

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: @Crou Rhel 7.6 installed on VirtualBox

Comment: Hello all can someone please help me with this?

Comment: @Stramzik did you solve this?